# Way to conditionally instantiate general struct where fields are typed to ZST or a concrete type

Tags: rust

I need to instantiate a struct that can have 15 or 1 parameters (by reading a file). All of them are different(one u32 other maybe f32), and have different sizes (not 15 different sizes, there are three sizes, 2 bytes, 4 bytes, 8 bytes). It all depends on a 16 bit mask. And I need memory optimization as there could be possibly millions of these little buggers (or even more).

So my first thought (I'm still learning Rust) was to use something like this.

```
struct test<A, B, C, D>
{
    w: A,
    x: B,
    y: C,
    d: D
}
```

I tested it with

```
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<test<(), f32, (), f32>>());
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<test<f32, f32, f32, f32>>());
```

And it was a size of 8 and 16 bytes, So now I knew that ZST could help me optimize away stuff that I didn't need.

But then when I tried something like this

```
let test1 = false;
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<test<( if test1 == true {f32} else {()}), f32, (), f32>>());
```

And I got a compilation error "expected type, found keyword if"

Then I started thinking about using something like this, and with 15 parameters it would be tedious to use (at best).

THEN I remembered that I need to know, during compile time, the size of a struct and I realised that I can only know it during runtime.

As I scoured the internet in search of a solution, one came to me, make it an array of bytes (or Vector) and serialise and deserialise it. So now I do have a working solution, and if performance will be an issue I can always transmute, but I'm still wondering, was there any way to make my first intuition solution work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* I cannot judge whether the following approach is sensible in your concrete case, but I successfully employ it. I would only go the route if you e.g. profiled that using generics to exploit ZST actually improves performance, as this solution involves some maintenance.

- If you stay with `struct Test<A, B, C, D>`, all users of `Test` will need to cope with the generic parameters `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, too. Rust definitely allows you to do this, but in can become quite cumbersome to actually carry it out, as Rust basically requires the parameters at each and every affected function.

  Grouping all the generic parameters into a single one may mitigate the problem, but that also is no panacea (because of e.g. individual trait bounds).
- As for the run-time/compile-time dichotomy, the following problem arises: The number of combination of generic parameters grows exponentially, and you could in theory certainly check for all of these run-time combinations and convert each of them into the respective compile-time parameters, but that takes a lot of effort to write and maintain.

  However, I once wrote a macro [`cartesian_match`](https://github.com/phimuemue/openschafkopf/blob/main/main/src/util/mod.rs#L76), which can help you with this (assume you have a `fn my_function<A, B, C>(t: Test<A, B, C>)`:

  ```
    macro_rules! call_function_with_test{($w: expr, $x: expr, $y: expr,) => {
        my_function(Test{w: $w, x: $x, y: $y})
    }}
    cartesian_match!(
        call_function_with_test,
        match (test1) {
            true => 3.1415/*f32*/,
            false => (),
        },
        match (test2) {
            true => 3.1415/*f32*/,
            false => true,
        },
        match (a_number) {
            0 => (1, false),
            1 => "Here a &str",
            2 => Some(Some(true)),
            _ => (),
        },
    )
  ```

  This macro generates all combinations that are possible given the values of `test1`, `test2` and `a_number` (in the example above its `2*2*4=16` different ones), and converts each combination to the respective combination of compile-time generic arguments put into a `Test`, and calls `my_function` on it. It bloats generated code (and compile times) quite a bit, but can be worth it.

Comment: If I understood correctly, for my code that would be 15! possible different struct, because 1 possibility is (f32, (), (), ()... () ), then (f32, u16, (), ()... () ) then (f32, (), f32, (), ()... () ) and so forth... if I'm correct that would be 1307674368000 possibilities, I would say that algoritmicaly around 0.1% of them makes sense, that's still alot, and exe would probably be in giga size... So only runtime shenaningans are feasible for me, I really don't see any other idiomatic way for me to achieve what I need to do. Only way that could work is if Rust could generate struct at runtime.